# How to implement an empty game object location when instantiating game objects through a unity editor tool?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got the cloning down on my custom unity Editor window but I am having trouble implementing an empty game object transform coordinates into it.

[image: my current code]

I got the public transform onto the script (named "parent") which will appear in my editor window, but I am having troubles trying to use it as the origin point to spawn times from the x and y axis. if anyone knows what is the line of code to implement it into line 41 (and or 42) let me know. thank you!

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have:

```
Vector2 spawnPos = new Vector2(parent);
```

`parent` is a `Transform`, and their is no constructor for `Vector2(Transform)`.
You need to pass the individual parameters like this:

```
Vector2 spawnPos = new Vector2(parent.position.x,parent.position.y);
```

or

```
Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(parent.position.x,parent.position.y,parent.position.z);
```

Comment: or just `Vector2 spawnPos = parent.position;` ;)